# TypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Below is the code, ive also tried the $regex method, it only gives me the 'Cant use $regex' error.

```
let query : any;
        if (data.search.length > 0) {
            query = { _id: new RegExp(`^${data.search}.*`), accountId };
        } else {
            query = { accountId };
        }

        const orders: any = await TEMPOrders.find(query)

            .lean()
            .exec();
```

Comment: The MongoDB ObjectId must be 12 bytes. In you query `_id` represents the ObjectId and your `RegExp()` is returning something other than the required 12 bytes. [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, how would you suggest if I want to search by _id and using regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **ObjectId()** for mongoose _id field for querying and the search value should also be an ObjectId,otherwise it will throw an error of string must be of length 12 bytes or 24 hex characters.

As **_id** is the primary key and it defines each documents uniquely in the collection. So **ObjectId** is used for comparison or for querying _id.

Import ObjectId as shown below:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId 

query = { _id: ObjectId(data.search), accountId };
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error must convert to `objectID` and also add `term()`

```js
var ObjectId = require(mongodb).ObjectId

var id = (req.body.id).term();
db.col.findOne({'_id':ObjectId(id)},(err,doc)=>{
 if(err){
   console.log(err)
 }else{
   console.log(doc)
 }
})
```